# How to restrict opening of the same window again and maximized the window if its minimized like Outlook using WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF project which have **list box collections**. When i clicked one of the items from the list box collections, the respective item's detailed information's opened with separate window. We can have multiple window like Outlook.

If i click on one item from list box, it will open with new window, if i click the same item means another window open with same information. In outlook if already opened means it will maximized the window which is already opened.

Comment: Perhaps you can keep track of the items that are already open (Maybe add the item to a list before opening the window), and before opening the new window, simply check to see if the item has already been opened.

Comment: RelatedItemsFullViewVM fullviewVM = new  RelatedItemsFullViewVM();   RelatedItemsFullView fullView = new  RelatedItemsFullView();

                fullviewVM.Id = SelectedRelatedItem.Id;
                fullviewVM.Platform = SelectedRelatedItem.Platform;
                fullviewVM.Control = SelectedRelatedItem.Control;
                fullviewVM.Title = SelectedRelatedItem.Title;
                fullviewVM.Status = SelectedRelatedItem.Status;
                fullviewVM.RelatedItemsHeader = RelatedItemsHeader;
                fullView.DataContext = fullviewVM;
                fullView.Show();

Answer (score 0):

To get all windows opened in you application use this method :

```
public Window getWindow(String Title)
{
Window windowObject = null;

foreach (Window window in System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows)
{
    if (window.Title == Title)
    {
        windowObject = window;
    }
}
return windowObject;
```

}

Of course, you will have to provide the title, which i think can be found on your ListBoxItem Content.

Use this to maximize it:

```
  windowObject.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

**Edit 1**

[image]

It works for me, on the GUI thread i am getting the Windows collection. I have pinned the items in that collection for the sake of accuracy.

As you see on my Loaded event :

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Window wnd = new Window();
            wnd.Title = "Title " + i.ToString();
            wnd.Show();
        }
```

I am instantiating two new fresh windows and they are shown up in the snip. I am not sure what more to say...

Comment: Hi Olaru Mircea, Everytime the windowobject return null only. I have passed the title of each window.